# Attach to an existing ssh tunnel

Tags: networking, ssh, ssh-tunneling

I have an existing ssh tunnel which connects machine `A` to `C` over `B`.

```
#user@A: ssh -N user@B -L 9999:C:9999
```

Is there any way to create a new ssh tunnel on `D` and attach it to the existing tunnel so that i can connect machine `D` to `C`? I tried to use

```
#user@D: ssh -N user@A -L 9999:C:9999
```

but I get a `no route to host` error when trying to connect to `C` with

```
#user@D: telnet localhost 9999
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Providing you have already set up your tunnel on A to C via B, then

You want

```
#user@D: ssh -N user@A -L 9999:localhost:9999

#user@D: telnet localhost 9999
```

Answer (score 1):

You are just creating another tunnel, it is not connecting to the existing tunnel. You probably want to connect to "localhost" on machine A instead (instead of C, which is already tunneled through B from A).

Comment: Ok, you mean by `#user@D: ssh -N user@A -L 9999:A:9999`? This just gives me a connection refused error.